# Android SQLite, update specific field from specific row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to update a specific column in my record within SQLite - the object has various attributes, but I just want to update a single field within that row. Here are my codes:

```
public boolean updateFavorite(String email, int isFavorite){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(EMAIL, email);
    args.put(IS_FAV, isFavorite);

    int i = db.update(TABLE_FAVORITES, args, EMAIL + "=" + email, null);

    return i > 0;
}
```

I am using the email for my where clause, i.e update record from favorites, set isFavorite to (given value) where email is (passed in value).

There is a problem with my query, which was caught by logcat, as shown below

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@sjisis": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Favorites SET email=?,isFavorite=? WHERE email=sjkshs@sjisis.com
```

Can anyone help me identify what is wrong with my codes to produce this error?

P.S my `FavoriteObject` class has other attributes other than just `email` and `isFavorite`, but in this case I am not trying to update them at all

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about the email address, perhaps the @. perhaps try `int i = db.update(TABLE_FAVORITES, args, EMAIL + "= ' " + email + "'", null);` ie. single quotes around the email address..

Comment: Yup hahaha it was all a careless mistake. you could put this in the answers so i can accept it! thanks mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's complaining about the email address, perhaps the @.

try

```
int i = db.update(TABLE_FAVORITES, args, EMAIL + "= ' " + email + "'", null);
```

ie. single quotes around the email address.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make email in where clause be argument too, i try to change your code but didn't test yet :

```
public boolean updateFavorite(String email, int isFavorite){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
values.put(EMAIL, email);
values.put(IS_FAV, isFavorite);
//add arguments for where clause
String[] args = new String[]{email};

int i = db.update(TABLE_FAVORITES, values, "EMAIL=?", args);

return i > 0;
}
```